# Write to a file using a for loop

Tags: c#, file, for-loop

This is a beginners question but the true is I never needed to use a method like this!
So I´ll need your patience..
I have several strings named t1, t2, t3, t4...and i want to write them to a file, one at each line
so i open the file ..

```
string t1 = "aaa";
string t2 = "bbb";
string t3 = "ccc";
//10 strings

for (int i = 1; i<= 10; i++)
{
    string key = "t" + i;
    strLine = convertToFile(key);
    f.WriteLine(strLine);
}
f.Close();
```

Like this all I get in the file is
    t1
    t2
    t3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

better store your strings in `List<string>` and then use this method:

```
File.WriteAllLines(filePath, lines);
```

it will store your list of strings in file at `filePath`

to create list from your strings do:

```
var lines = new List<string>{ t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t10};
```

Comment: that was the original idea.. but i was trying to do in a different way.

Comment: @user3061846 why you would like to do it other way?

Comment: Because I need to preform several operations with that strings, so I was trying to simplify..But I just realised that I was complicating the code...Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use a collection instead of single variables:

```
var allStrings = new List<string>();
allStrings.Add("aaa");
allStrings.Add("bbb");
allStrings.Add("ccc");
// ...

using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(path))
{
   foreach(string str in allStrings)
       w.WriteLine(str );
}
```

or more concise using [`File.WriteAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
File.WriteAllLines(path, allStrings);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple as that

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.AppendLine("aaa");
sb.AppendLine("bbb");
sb.AppendLine("ccc");

System.IO.File.WriteAllText("D:\fileName.txt", sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

The point is that you cannot access variables in the way your code outlines. What you do in the for loop is constructing the variable name you what to access. But you just generate a string that is named like your variables, but you cannot access them through a string. A variable in C# is a reference, the name you give it does not really matter. So all answers above solve your problem but you should carefully think about the result you expected from your code and why it does not work that way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to convert a string (from a user input perhaps) to a local variable then you would be better using if or case.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                string key = "t" + i;
                if (key == "t1")
                {
                f.WriteLine(t1);
                }
                else if (key == "t2")
                {
                f.WriteLine(t2);
                }

            }
```

Or to build on Tim Schmelter's Answer

```
var t = new List<string>();
        t.Add("aaa");
        t.Add("bbb");
        t.Add("ccc");
        // ...

        using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(path))
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                string key = "t"+i;

                if (key == "t1")
                {
                w.WriteLine(t[1]);
                }
                else if (key == "t2")
                {
                    w.WriteLine(t[2]);
                }

            }

        }
```

Or without the string

```
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                w.WriteLine(t[i]);
            }
```

Comment: first: why you are using multiple if's? second: why you are building key in second example? Why not: `t[i]`? Simplify your code.

Comment: Building the key in the loop because the questioner built the key in the loop. For clarity I will add a third example without the string.